# Primefaces Resources not loaded when including commons project

Tags: maven, primefaces

I have two ear-projects (**projectA** and **projectB**) with an ejb and an web module working perfectly standalone. Both projects use **primefaces 6.0** with the **spark-layout**.

My goal is to integrate projectA into projectB so that projectA can still run standalone aswell as part of projectB.

For this I added a new module (**projectA-web-commons**) and moved the `src/main/webapp/resources/` folder with all content from **projectA-web** into **projectA-web-commons** `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` folder.

**projectA-web** has only left with an `faces-config.xml` and an `web.xml` in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` folder.

I can deploy **projectA** standalone and the application works as good as before but when I add **projectA-web-commons** to **projectB** as a module primefaces font and image resources didnt load.[image]

From Chrome Developer tools I can see that the application tries to load e.g. the font resource from `../projectB/fonts/...` without **projectA-web-commons** the resource is loaded from `../projectB/javax.faces.resources/fonts...`

What I'm doing wrong? 
Additionally I use the UnmappedResourceHandler from Omnifaces in both projects. Not sure if the problem comes with this ResourceHandler.

Comment: I could figure out a little bit more. The ressources which are not loaded are included in a css file like this:  
@font-face {
 font-family: 'lucida';
 src: url("#{resource['spark-layout:fonts/lucida.ttf']}");
}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. It has to do with UnmappedResourceHandler from Omnifaces. It was declared in several faces-config.xmls in the submodules using this line:

```
<resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
```

After deleting the obsolete one, it worked for me.